# Defenestrar a tag [função]

Tags: debate, status-pronto, tags

Vi hoje esta tag:

[função](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fun%c3%a7%c3%a3o)

Acredito que é absolutamente desnecessária. Em todas as perguntas nas quais foi utilizada até o momento, ela é redundante. Não consigo imaginar nenhum caso na qual ela não seria, na verdade. Mesmo que alguém quisesse perguntar o que uma função realmente é, acredito que as tags de linguagem ou tecnologia mais específicas dariam conta do recado.

Seria o caso de se eliminar a tag [função](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fun%c3%a7%c3%a3o)?

Comment: A tag [funções] cai no mesmo problema, certo? Essa ainda existe, com 15 perguntas.

Comment: Vou olhar melhor todas as perguntas com a tag [funções], mas olhando só os títulos parece ter várias em que faz sentido manter.

Comment: @bfavaretto Eu acho o contrário. Essa tag parece estar sendo abusada.

Answer (score 6):

Você tinha toda razão. Problema resolvido :)

Nenhum problema na *tag* em si. Quando existir um motivo para usá-la ela pode ser criada sem problemas, mas para acrescentar alguma informação útil para o problema.

Comment: Resolvido por ora. Vai reaparecer com certeza. No SO, a tag tem quase 30k perguntas.

Comment: Por isso que é importante não deixar ficar inadministrável. Claro que pra gente é mais fácil.