# Qual das tags de função devemos usar?

Tags: debate, status-pronto, tags

Há um ano atrás discutimos a necessidade da tag para "funções" <sup>[1](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1371/129) [2](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1786/129)</sup>. Com o crescimento do site há hoje muitas perguntas com essa tag. Umas justificadas, outras não.

Partindo do principio que já há um numero de perguntas relacionadas com funções onde vale a pena a tag, a próxima pergunta é: qual delas usar [função](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fun%c3%a7%c3%a3o), [funções](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fun%c3%a7%c3%b5es), [função-anônima](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fun%c3%a7%c3%a3o-an%c3%b4nima) ou [function](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/function)?

Se houver consenso em qual delas usar podemos mudar as tags nas perguntas para organizarmos essas tags melhor. Seria também interessante defenirmos o escopo no qual se aplica usar a tag.

Comment: Eu não utilizava nenhuma.

Comment: @JorgeB. coloca isso como resposta, assim outros com a mesma opinião podem votar na ideia. Eu acho que é prático para organizar perguntas e para as encontrar, mas também imagino um cenário em que as abolimos.

Comment: feito @Sergio .

Comment: Ao meu ver uma pergunta com o termo função(ões) serviria para qualquer duvida que o foco seja as `funções`, agora `função-anônima` para mim me parece bem especifico e não pode ser necessariamente comparada com as outras sugestões, como neste uso que fiz http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/50979/3635 Sobre a tag `função` eu realmente acho que ela dificilmente terá uma duvida especifica, mas se for para opinar eu escolheria `função`.

Answer (score 8):

Pra mim hoje já existe justificativa para pelo menos uma tag sobre funções, que seria usada para:

- Dúvidas sobre o conceito de função.
- Dúvidas sobre a implementação desse conceito em determinada linguagem.

Mas **não deveria ser usada para**:

- Dúvidas sobre alguma função nativa da linguagem X
- Dúvidas sobre a lógica interna de uma função que você está construindo.

A maioria das perguntas com as tags [função](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fun%c3%a7%c3%a3o) e [funções](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fun%c3%a7%c3%b5es) são desse segundo tipo, e [isso só tende a piorar](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1786/tag-function-e-fun%c3%a7%c3%a3o#comment5591_1868). É, sou pessimista, mas ficarei muito feliz se a comunidade provar que eu estou errado. Por enquanto, o volume de perguntas com essas tags é gerenciável. Por enquanto. Então é hora de tentar botar essas tags em ordem e ver se dá pra manter em ordem. Se formos vencidos pela desordem, paciência, mas pelo menos teremos tentado.

Proponho a seguinte organização:

- [função](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fun%c3%a7%c3%a3o)  ← [funções](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fun%c3%a7%c3%b5es) (a segunda como sinônimo da primeira).
- [função-anônima](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fun%c3%a7%c3%a3o-an%c3%b4nima): vale a pena manter por ser um subtipo de função muito usado.
- [function](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/function): eliminar ou transformar sinônimo de função.

Fusões e sinônimos de tags são coisas simples de os moderadores fazerem, se essa ideia parecer boa pra vocês. Mas peço ajuda da comunidade na parte manual, que seria uma faxina para remover as tags das perguntas onde elas não são necessárias (provavelmente, a maioria).

Comment: Concordo com o @bfavaretto, e sugiro a eliminação da tag [tag:function], pois se colocamos perguntas em inglês como fora de escopo, tags também deveriam ser. (apesar disso ser um pouco difícil no meio da programação, pois muitos termos não tem tradução)

Comment: @KaduAmaral Em geral sim, preferimos tags em português. Mas tem alguns termos técnicos que fica melhor usar em inglês.

Comment: Verdade, por isso depois que comentei lembrei disso e adicionei o "apesar"...

Answer (score 7):

Por mim acho que não faz sentido existirem essas tags. Normalmente, é implícito que estamos a trabalhar com funções. Era como colocar a tag [código](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%c3%b3digo) em quase todas as perguntas.

Para mim as tags devem identificar algum assunto, por exemplo a tag [c](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c) diz-nos que estamos com um problema em C e quem seguir essa tag poderá resolve-lo. A tag [função](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fun%c3%a7%c3%a3o) não indica absolutamente nada.

Comment: Eu concordaria totalmente, exceto pelo que o @bfavaretto disse. O site pode ter perguntas teóricas ou abstratas sobre o conceito de funções, e nesse caso a tag seria mais útil. Mas restrita a um conjunto bem particular (e pequeno) de perguntas

Comment: Concordo, não vejo um ponto onde realmente seja significativo o uso dessa tag com exceção de perguntas muito específicas.